# Erro unexpected 'use' (T_USE) ao usar autoload

Tags: php, facebook, php-autoload

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de pastas e arquivos:

```
-api
  -v1
  -libs
    -Slim
    -Facebook
      -autoload.php
  -index.php
  -login.php
```

Dentro do "index.php" faço o include do "login.php":

```
require_once 'login.php';
```

Dentro do "login.php" faço o include do ficheiro "libs/Facebook/autoload.php" e logo em seguida tento utilizar uma classe:

```
require_once 'libs/Facebook/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
```

O seguinte erro é retornado:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

O "autoload.php" contém o seguinte código:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class){
   $prefix = 'Facebook\\';
   $base_dir = __DIR__;
   $len = strlen($prefix);
   if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
      return;
   }
   $relative_class = substr($class, $len);
   $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';
   if (file_exists($file)) {
      require $file;
   }
});
```

O que estou a fazer de errado para o autoload não funcionar corretamente?

Comment: O `use Facebook\FacebookSession;` está sendo chamado dentro de um método ou função?

Comment: Qual a versão do php que está usando?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19055649/1518921):

Isto ocorre porque você provavelmente definiu o namespace dentro de um método ou função, leia sobre [PHP: Using Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> O `use` deve ser declarado no escopo mais externo de um arquivo (no alcance global) ou dentro de declarações `namespace`. Isso ocorre porque a importação é feita em tempo de compilação e não tempo de execução, de modo que não pode ser bloco escopo.

Para resolver você deve mover o `use` para fora de qualquer função ou classe.

Supondo que esteja assim:

```
function initiate () {
    require_once 'libs/Facebook/autoload.php';
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    ...
}
```

Faça isto:

```
require_once 'libs/Facebook/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;

function initiate () {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sim, estava, mudei o require_once 'libs/Facebook/autoload.php'; e use Facebook\FacebookSession; para o "index.php" fora da função. Agora da o seguinte erro: Class 'FacebookSession' not found in...

Comment: Não resolveu, o autoload ainda não funciona, retornar o seguinte erro: Class 'FacebookSession' not found in C:\wamp\www\iassistu\api\v1\login.php on line 22, na linha 22 tenho FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FACEBOOK_APP_ID,FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);

Comment: @FilipeMoraes A tá o primeiro problema resolveu, este agora é um novo problema, pelo que vejo o autoload.php não está carregando a classe. Edite a questão e poste o conteudo inteiro do **autoload.php** e o conteudo de **login.php**

Comment: Sim está carregando, inseri a linha FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication dentro do index.php e funcionou, dento do login.php.

Comment: Sim, resolvido. Inseri o "use" no index.php e no login.php para utilizar a classe tenho que colocar o "Facebook\" antes: Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FACEBOOK_APP_ID,FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);

Comment: @FilipeMoraes :) Legal obrigado por contribuir está informação e por aceitar a minha resposta