# Problema com use em PHP

Tags: php, amazon-aws, sdk

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que envia uma imagem para um bucket na amazon e estou usando o [sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/master/src) puro

Para enviar uso o seguinte código:

```
function especifica(){
    require '..\..\lib\aws\aws-autoloader.php';
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;

    define("ACCESS_KEY_AMAZON", "");
    define("SECRET_KEY_AMAZON", "");

    try {
        $clientS3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'region'   => 'região',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'key'    => ACCESS_KEY_AMAZON,
            'secret' => SECRET_KEY_AMAZON
        ));
        $response = $clientS3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => "bucket",
            'Key'    => "profile_picture/".$_POST['idusuario'].".png",
            'SourceFile' => $_POST['hidden_cropped'],
        ));

        die(var_dump($response));
        echo "Objeto postado com sucesso, endereco <a href='{$response['ObjectURL']}'>{$response['ObjectURL']}</a>";
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        log_errors( "Edit picture, upload to amazon S3".PHP_EOL."Exception: ".$e);
    }
}
```

Acontece que a minha `API` possui mais de uma função no mesmo arquivo, tipo alterar foto, alterar informações básicas, cancelar assinatura, alterar senha e por ai vai.

Por isso preferi manter o `require` pra ser executado somente dentro da função alterar foto, porém estava recebendo direto o erro:

> Erro unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Depois de pesquisar sobre eu descobri que o `namespace` `use` só pode ser declarado `no escopo mais externo de um arquivo`.

Fonte: [Erro unexpected 'use' (T_USE) ao usar autoload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51014/erro-unexpected-use-t-use-ao-usar-autoload)

Ok, coloquei o `use` no escopo mais externo, mais ou menos desse modo:

```
require '..\..\lib\aws\aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

function especifica(){    
    define("ACCESS_KEY_AMAZON", "");
    define("SECRET_KEY_AMAZON", "");

    try {
        $clientS3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'region'   => 'região',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'key'    => ACCESS_KEY_AMAZON,
            'secret' => SECRET_KEY_AMAZON
        ));
        $response = $clientS3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => "bucket",
            'Key'    => "profile_picture/".$_POST['idusuario'].".png",
            'SourceFile' => $_POST['hidden_cropped'],
        ));

        die(var_dump($response));
        echo "Objeto postado com sucesso, endereco <a href='{$response['ObjectURL']}'>{$response['ObjectURL']}</a>";
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        log_errors( "Edit picture, upload to amazon S3".PHP_EOL."Exception: ".$e);
    }
}
```

E funcionou, só que queria saber se isso afeta minhas outras funções? No tempo de carregamento principalmente, já que o sdk da amazon tem 6MB.

Comment: Qual versão do php vc usa?

Comment: `PHP Version 7.0.14-1`
Rodando em um servidor Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O operador `use` serve como alias para namespaces. Há outra finalidade de uso no qual passa um argumento por referência, mas não é o caso aqui portanto o foco será apenas referente ao que perguntou:

> E funcionou, só que queria saber se isso afeta minhas outras funções?
>   No tempo de carregamento principalmente, já que o sdk da amazon tem
>   6MB.

O operador `use` cria apenas um "atalho" (alias). Não carrega o objeto alvo do alias. Portanto, não precisa ter preocupação com custo de memória, etc. É óbvio que há um custo referente ao uso do operador, no entanto os objetos não são carregados automaticamente.

O que pode acontecer de errado no seu aplicativo é, se o aplicativo não possuir uma boa organização, pode ocorrer algum conflito de nomes, mas é algo incomum e só vai acontecer se escrever o aplicativo de uma forma muito desorganizada, declarando funções, classes ou namespaces com nomenclatura comumente usada, aumentando chances de conflito com sistemas/bibliotecas terceiras que estiver importando no seu projeto (include, require)

É essa uma das finalidades de uso do namespace. Evitar esse problema de conflito de funções com nomes iguais.

Um detalhe importante no seu caso é que está aplicando o alias para o escopo global. Ou seja, você pode invocar as classes que estão sob o namespace `Aws\S3\S3Client` sem precisar especificar o namespace.

Exemplo, num trecho do código invoca `S3Client::factory()`. Isso só é possível porque o alias `Aws\S3\S3Client` foi aplicado para a base do escopo global. Se precisar invocar uma função ou classe fora desse namespace, terá que especificar o path completo ou relativo com os devidos recuos.

Particularmente prefiro especificar um alias ao invés de jogar para o root:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client as AWS;
```

Assim basta invocar desse modo: `AWS\S3Client::factory()`. Mas isso depende muito do projeto. Se o projeto não usa nenhum outro namespace, pode jogar o alias para o root como está fazendo. Claro, desde que esteja ciente sobre conflitos de nomes.

Para não ter preocupações desse tipo, apenas crie um padrão para os seus projetos, organizando-os sempre dentro um namespace próprio.

obs: Sugiro que edite o título e a pergunta para algo mais adequado.

Para entender melhor como fazer perguntas: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/4793)

Answer (score 3):

Estou considerando que você está lidando com uma aplicação legada e que não convém adotar as melhores práticas de carregamento então, vejo que você pode deixar da forma que está sem comprometer a performance mas também pode remover a linha do `use` e utilizar o `fully qualified name` do objeto, colocando a barra invertida no início, exemplo:

```
<?php
    require_once '..\..\lib\aws\aws-autoloader.php';
    $clientS3 = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory( //...
```

Comment: mas e quanto a forma de utilizando o `use`, isso afeta a performance? Digo, faz o carregamento de toda a classe da `aws sdk`, pra todas as funções, mesmo que não usem ela?

Comment: acho que você não precisa se preocupar com isso pois a otimização é feita no Core da linguagem