# Estou usando dompdf e obtendo o seguinte erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) na linha em que referencia o namespace

Tags: php, dompdf

```
function contasApagar() {

        $fornecedorDAO = new fornecedoresDAO();
        $retfornecedor = $fornecedorDAO->buscarTodos();

        $forma_pagtoDAO = new forma_pagtoDAO();
        $retformapagamento = $forma_pagtoDAO->buscarTodas();

        $contaDAO = new contas_pagarDAO();
        $retorno = $contaDAO->filtrarData();


        // include autoloader
        require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

        //referenciando o namespace
        use  Dompdf \ Dompdf ;

        // instanciando o dompdf
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();

        //lendo o arquivo HTML correspondente
        $html = file_get_contents('visao/relatorios/contasApagar_pdf.php');
        //require_once "visao/relatorios/contasApagar_pdf.php";

        //inserindo o HTML que queremos converter
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

        //Definindo o tipo de fonte padrão
        $dompdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'Times New Roman');

        // Definindo o papel e a orientação
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

        // Renderizando o HTML como PDF
        $dompdf->render();

        // Enviando o PDF para o browser
        $dompdf->stream();

}
```

Comment: Me parece que tem algo relacionado aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51014/8063

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas declarações de namespace e use geralmente é no início do arquivo

Comment: Se fosse chutar, diria que o uso deve ser feito dessa forma: `function contasApagar() use (Dompdf\Dompdf) { /* ... */ }`, mas é apenas uma ideia. Mas por que não declarar o uso da classe no início do arquivo?

Comment: use e namespace é no topo do arquivo.

Comment: Resolvido use namespace é no topo do arquivo.